# Domain Multiple inheritance and manyToMany relation removeFrom not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I prepared some complex model structure due to content management businnes.

My main content model likes as following code.

```
    class CmsContent implements Comparable<CmsContent>, Taggable, Serializable {
          Set<CmsContent> contents
          static hasMany = [contents:CmsContent]
    }
```

Other Content Model extends from above

```
   class Menu extends CmsContent {
   }

   class Image extends CmsContent {
   }

   class Video extends CmsContent {       
   }
```

On Controller side when ever add Image to Menu it is perfectly working

```
def addContent(){

        Menu menuInstance = Menu.get(params.id)
        if (menuInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        CmsContent content = CmsContent.get(params.contentId)
        if (content == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        menuInstance.addToContents(content)
        menuInstance.save(flush: true)

        request.withFormat {

            '*'{
                def result =[:]  ;
                result.status ='success';
                render result as JSON
            }
        }
    }


def removeContent(){

    Menu menuInstance = Menu.get(params.id)
    if (menuInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    long id = Long.valueOf(params.contentId)
    CmsContent content = cmsContent.contents.find { it.id == id }
    if (content == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    menuInstance.removeFromContents(content)
    menuInstance.save(flush: true)

    request.withFormat {
        '*'{
            def result =[:]  ;
            result.status ='success';
            render result as JSON
        }
    }

}
```

But when I tried to remove facing following exception.

```
Cannot get property 'name' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
```

I tracked down in grails code in **DomainClassGrailsPlugin**.
I realize that addTo Method and line 368 checking **prop.otherSide** attribute

```
if (prop.bidirectional && prop.otherSide) {
}
```

unfortunately removeTo method not check **prop.otherSide** attribute, therefore name field throwing the exception.

```
if (prop.bidirectional) {
   if (prop.manyToMany) {
        String name = prop.otherSide.name
        arg[name]?.remove(delegate)
   } else {
        arg[prop.otherSide.name] = null
   }
}
```

What do you think ? Do you agree with me ?

Comment: I forked grails-core and made necessary fix on grails-plugin-domain-class module.just built it and copied in lib directory. Currently,  everything seem ok. I also push the correction to github  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/460. fyi.

Comment: My pull request accepted by graemerocher. He has just merged the fix with 2.3.x release.